# Time Looping Python

Tags: python, loops

How can I write code to loop in time python? I want this code loop 10 minutes in python.

```
msList =[]
msg = str(raw_input('Input Data :'))
msgList.append(msg)
```

I do not wanna use `crontab` because I want this code looping in my program.

Comment: Only sleep 10 minutes or sleep user entered time?

Comment: @KevinGuan only 10 minutes, but in 10 minutes I still can run the code. Thank you

Comment: So you want run the program for 10 minutes and then exit? Or sleep 10 minutes then run the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
import time

t_end = time.time() + 60 * 10
msgList =[]
while time.time() < t_end:
    msg = str(raw_input('Input Data :'))
    msgList.append(msg)
    print(msgList)
```

Credit goes to this post:

[Python loop to run for certain amount of seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24374620/python-loop-to-run-for-certain-amount-of-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `sleep` function from the `time` module. This should do what you're asking:

```
from time import sleep
msList =[]
while True:
    msg = str(raw_input('Input Data :'))
    msgList.append(msg)
    sleep(600)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I want in 10 minutes I can run code for input.

Answer (score 0):

```
from time import sleep

while True:

    msList = []
    msg = str(raw_input('Input Data :'))
    msgList.append(msg)

    sleep(600)
```

This will keep the program running and sleep for 600s or 10 minutes after it executes the first three lines inside the `while` loop.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I want in 10 minutes I can run code for input.

Comment: It is asking for input after 10 minutes, set it to `sleep(5)` and test it. After 5 seconds it'll ask for input and wait until you give it something.