# While loop for 300seconds in python

Tags: python, while-loop

I am new in python 
I want to run my while loop for 300seconds or upto 300s 
After 300seconds it must terminate 
How I can write program in python 
Plz help.

Comment: You can easily do that with the sleep function of the time library, why using a loop?

Comment: `time.sleep(300)`. What's your _real_ problem?

Comment: What have you tried?  Please post the code you are working on, it makes it a lot easier to help when you do.

Comment: @JoshuaSmith a useful "What have you tried" for once.

Comment: Also, what do you mean exactly about the 300 secs? What if the content of the loop takes 299 seconds to run once? Checking the break criteria once per loop may cause it to run for 598 seconds. You've given no context on what you're trying to do.

Comment: I think you want to have something like a timer. Check out `time.time`  in the official Python documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python loop to run for certain amount of seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24374620/python-loop-to-run-for-certain-amount-of-seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this, which will loop 300 seconds

```
import time

start_time = time.time()

while (time.time() - start_time) < 300:
    print("/", end='')

print("End.")
```