# How do I stop this loop after 5 seconds?

Tags: python

I made this box of code and the loop goes on forever, I want the loop to go for 5 seconds then stop completely. (also import time and random are put in above in the code)

I haven't tried much, quite lost on how to do this.

```py
def case1():
    start = 1
    while True:
        int = randint(0,3)
        if int < 1:
            print('Blue')
            sleep(0.05)

        elif int < 2:
            print('Purple')
            sleep(0.05)

        elif int <= 3:
            print('Pink')
            sleep(0.05)
```

I need the loop to stop, after 5 seconds

Comment: Add an `exit()` after the time to sleep is done

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python loop to run for certain amount of seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24374620/python-loop-to-run-for-certain-amount-of-seconds)

Comment: use `time` or `datetime` functions

Comment: Since you know it has to stop at 5 seconds, why not use a for loop with `range(5)`, and have it `sleep(1)` at the end of each loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop the loop after 5 seconds you can use `time()` from `time`:

```
from time import time

def case1():
    start = time() + 5
    while time() < start:
        num = randint(0,3)
        if num < 1:
            print("Blue")
            sleep(0.05)
        elif num < 2:
            print("Purple")
            sleep(0.05)
        elif num <= 3:
            print("Pink")
            sleep(0.05)
```